# ¿Cómo hacer que un slider tenga opacidad?

Tags: javascript, css3

Muy buenos días, he intentado hacer que la imagen del slider tenga una opacidad como la siguiente imagen que adjunto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que la imagen mostrada no es un slider, es un elemento div , a lo que voy es que quiero que el slider tenga esa opacidad.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/banner.jpg" alt="Slider Image">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-centered">
                        <div class="margin-b-40">
                            <h1 class="carousel-title">Hi-Tech Design</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet consectetur adipiscing dolore magna aliqua <br/> enim minim estudiat veniam siad venumus dolore</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-theme btn-theme-sm btn-white-brd text-uppercase">Explore</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/banner2.jpg" alt="Slider Image">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-centered">
                        <div class="margin-b-40">
                            <h2 class="carousel-title">Hi-Tech Design</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet consectetur adipiscing dolore magna aliqua <br/> enim minim estudiat veniam siad venumus dolore</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-theme btn-theme-sm btn-white-brd text-uppercase">Explore</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Mi resultado adjunto la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden darse cuenta, las imágenes no tienen esa opacidad que necesito hacer, he intentado con CSS3: opacity; pero tampoco se opacan las imágenes; ¿alguien podría orientarme de cómo resolverlo?
Estoy utilizando la librería Bootstrap 3.
NOTA: Soy nuevo en CSS3 y JavaScript no tengo mucho conocimiento al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una forma muy sencilla, usando `::before`, es decir un seodoelemento que podemos crear dinamicamente con css en un contenedor que elijas, el de las imagenes por poner un ejemplo y sobreponer este encima de cada imagen, con un color de fondo y una opacidad.

El código sería así:

```
.contenedor-imagenes{
  position: relative;
}

.contenedor-imagenes::before{
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;  
}
```

Te doy un ejemplo más visual de lo que quiero decir, pero cambiando el contenedor de imágenes por el id de tu carrusel: `carousel-example-generic`

```css
#carousel-example-generic{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#carousel-example-generic *{
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.imagen-ejemplo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:
    url('http://picsum.photos/1200/1200?=image260');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: slider-ejemplo 2s infinite ease;
}

#carousel-example-generic::before{
  content: 'con el seudolemento';
  color: white; 
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
  animation: conysin ease 8s infinite; 
}

/*ESTO LO PUEDES IGNORAR ES SOLO PARA MOSTRARTE UN EJEMPLO DE COMO SE VERIA EN EL SLIDER*/
@keyframes slider-ejemplo{
  0%{ transform: translateX(100%) }
  30%, 70%{ transform: translateX(0%) }
  100%{ transform: translateX(-100%) }
}
@keyframes conysin{
  5%,45%{ 
    content: 'con el seudoelemento'; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
  }
  55%,95%{ 
    content: 'sin el seudoelemento'; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.0); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic">
  <!--contenido del slider-->
  <figure class="imagen-ejemplo">
  </figure>
</div>
```

```
<!--Queda claro? Es un poco complicado si sabes o no usar 
* `z-index` y la **sobreposición de elementos en css en 
* un mismo espacio**? Si no lo sabes, déjame un comentario 
* y lo agrego a la respuesta.-->
```

### Explicación breve sobre de Z-INDEX

`Z-index` es una propiedad que permite controlar qué elemento va encima de otro, dependiendo de si ocupan el mismo espacio.

Entre más alto el valor, más por encima estaran de los de menor valor o que sencillamente no tengan ninguno.

Solo funciona si los elementos tienen declarada un tipo de posición, diferente a la que tienen por defecto que es `static`. Es decir: `position: relative | absolute | fixed`.

Otra condición, es que solo funciona con elementos hermanos o en el mismo nivel de anidación. Es decir, poniendo un ejemplo.

```
<p class="padre hermano">
  <a class="hijo"></a>
</p>
<p class="padre hermano">
  <a class="hijo"></a>
</p>
```

Z index, funcionará perfectamente entre padres o mejor dicho entre hermanos, en la estructura anterior, pero no funcionará igual entre los hijos, porque si los padres tienen declarado un z-index, se seguirá priorizando el valor declarado en ellos.

Pero mejor de te dejo un ejemplo para que analices lo que te digo:

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
p{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.grupo { display: inline-block; margin-left: 0.5em; }

.capa1{ z-index: 1; }
.capa2{ z-index: 2; }

.cyan { background-color: cyan; }
.lime { background-color: lime; }

.padre{  width:  100px; height: 100px; }
.hijo { padding: 0.4em; background-color: whitesmoke; } 

.dos{ margin-top: -2em; }
```

```html
<div class="grupo">
  <p class="padre cyan uno hermano capa2">
    padre capa2
    <a class="hijo">
      hijo
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="padre lime dos hermano capa1">
    padre capa1
    <a class="hijo">
      hijo
    </a>
  </p>
</div><div class="grupo">
  <p class="padre cyan uno hermano capa1">
    padre capa1
    <a class="hijo">
      hijo
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="padre lime dos hermano capa2">
    padre capa2
    <a class="hijo">
      hijo
    </a>
  </p>
</div><div class="grupo">
  <p class="padre cyan uno hermano capa1">
    padre capa1
    <a class="hijo capa2">
      hijo capa2
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="padre lime dos hermano capa2">
    padre capa2
    <a class="hijo capa1">
      hijo capa1
    </a>
  </p>
</div><div class="grupo">
  <p class="padre cyan uno hermano capa2">
    padre capa1
    <a class="hijo capa1">
      hijo capa1
    </a>
  </p>
  <p class="padre lime dos hermano capa1">
    <a class="hijo capa2">
      hijo capa2
    </a><br/>
    padre capa2
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Buensa noches, respecto a: z-index no lo sé usar

Comment: @ArmandoBolaños actualicé mi respuesta para explicarte brevemente sobre la propiedad `z-index` y cómo funciona.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación @Edgar Gutiérrez

Answer (score 1):

En la primera primera imagen que muestras el "opacity" no esta aplicada a la imagen, sino a un elemento que esta encima de ella.
Puedes ayudarte de los pseudoelementos `::before` y `::after` para lograr el efecto o hacerlo de la siguiente forma y usando gradients (En este caso `radial-gradient`):

```css
#divpadre
{
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:250px;
}
img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#divopacity
{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 80%);
top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="divpadre">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml6qr.jpg">

<div id="divopacity">
</div>

</div>
```

```css
#divpadre
{
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:250px;
}
img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#divopacity
{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 80%);
top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="divpadre">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml6qr.jpg">

<div id="divopacity">
</div>

</div>
```